# How to force Tagify to only accept tags made of lowercase and underscores?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, tags

I'm using [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) for the `<input>` responsible for the tags in my application. I want each tag to be lowercase and to only have _ as special characters. I found a way to force this as I'm processing the input, but not to display to the user what's happening, e.g. interacting directly with the `<input>` itself.

The main problem is that the `<input>` element bound to Tagify is replaced by other elements and thus I can't interact directly with those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't quite found the perfect answer, but this seems to work okay:

```
var newSetTags = document.getElementById("new-set-tags");
var tagify = new Tagify(newSetTags, { pattern: /^[a-z][a-z_]+$/gm });
```

The pattern parameter validates the tags.

Comment: Why do you consider using `pattern` to be *"imperfect"*?